# Matplotlib worldmap plot with legend auto generate

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geoip, matplotlib-basemap

I am creating an open source framework with some co-workers to test software, files for malware, virus, ect.. We wanted to take the outbound connections we capture and plot them on a map of the world. I have been able to generate the map, and plot the data from a text file on the map. The text file is auto generated every time we do a scan. We will never know what IP address are in that file. Is there a way to:

1)How can I generate a Legend with the information that is being pulled from the database onto the map? (IP address, Country, Ciy)

2)Is there a way to have the colors of each dot be different?

3)Is there a way to show a connecting line from where the connection started from on the map to where it ended?

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python
# by Angelis Pseftis 5/17/2015

from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals, with_statement
import argparse
import contextlib
import requests
import sys
import csv
import matplotlib
# Anti-Grain Geometry (AGG) backend so GeoIP can be used 'headless' because Josh hates GUIs.'
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import GeoIP


def get_ip(ip_file):
    """
    Returns a list of IP addresses from a file containing one IP per line.
    """
    with contextlib.closing(ip_file):
        return [line.strip() for line in ip_file]


def get_lat_lon(ip_list=[], lats=[], lons=[]):
    """
    This function connects to the FreeGeoIP web service to get info from
    a list of IP addresses.
    Returns two lists (latitude and longitude).
    """
    print("Processing {} IPs...".format(len(ip_list)))
    for ip in ip_list:
        r = requests.get("https://freegeoip.net/json/" + ip)
        json_response = r.json()
        print("{ip}, {region_name}, {country_name}, {latitude}, {longitude}".format(**json_response))
        if json_response['latitude'] and json_response['longitude']:
            lats.append(json_response['latitude'])
            lons.append(json_response['longitude'])
    return lats, lons


def geoip_lat_lon(gi, ip_list=[], lats=[], lons=[]):
    """
    This function uses the MaxMind library and databases to geolocate IP addresses
    Returns two lists (latitude and longitude).
    """
    print("Processing {} IPs...".format(len(ip_list)))
    for ip in ip_list:
        try:
            r = gi.record_by_addr(ip)
        except Exception:
            print("Unable to locate IP: %s" % ip)
            continue
        if r is not None:
            print("%s {country_code} {latitude}, {longitude}".format(**r) % ip)
            lats.append(r['latitude'])
            lons.append(r['longitude'])
    return lats, lons


def get_lat_lon_from_csv(csv_file, lats=[], lons=[]):
    """
    Retrieves the last two rows of a CSV formatted file to use as latitude
    and longitude.
    Returns two lists (latitudes and longitudes).
    Example CSV file:
    119.80.39.54, Beijing, China, 39.9289, 116.3883
    101.44.1.135, Shanghai, China, 31.0456, 121.3997
    219.144.17.74, Xian, China, 34.2583, 108.9286
    64.27.26.7, Los Angeles, United States, 34.053, -118.2642
    """
    with contextlib.closing(csv_file):
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            lats.append(row[-2])
            lons.append(row[-1])

    return lats, lons


def generate_map(output, lats=[], lons=[]):
    """
    Using Basemap and the matplotlib toolkit, this function generates a map and
    puts a red dot at the location of every IP addresses found in the list.
    The map is then saved in the file specified in `output`.
    """
    print("Generating map and saving it to {}".format(output))
    m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='l')
    m.bluemarble()
    x, y = m(lons, lats)
    m.scatter(x, y, s=1, color='#ff0000', marker='o', alpha=0.3)
    plt.savefig(output, dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Visualize community on a map.')
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', dest="input", type=argparse.FileType('r'),
            help='Input file. One IP per line or, if FORMAT set to \'csv\', CSV formatted file ending with latitude and longitude positions',
            default=sys.stdin)
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', default='output.png', help='Path to save the file (e.g. /tmp/output.png)')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--format', default='ip', choices=['ip', 'csv'], help='Format of the input file.')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--service', default='f', choices=['f','m'], help='Geolocation service (f=FreeGeoIP, m=MaxMind local database)')
    parser.add_argument('-db', '--db', default='./GeoLiteCity.dat', help='Full path to MaxMind database file (default = ./GeoLiteCity.dat)')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    output = args.output

    if args.format == 'ip':
        ip_list = get_ip(args.input)
        if args.service == 'm':
            gi = GeoIP.open(args.db, GeoIP.GEOIP_STANDARD)
            lats, lons = geoip_lat_lon(gi, ip_list)
        else:  # default service
            lats, lons = get_lat_lon(ip_list)
    elif args.format == 'csv':
        lats, lons = get_lat_lon_from_csv(args.input)

    generate_map(output, lats, lons)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. please try to be more specific as of where is your problem in the code, what is the output, what is the expected output. also add just the relevant part of the code and not all of it

Comment: I have tried to clear my questions up. I left the entire code just in case they needed to see how i am doing things.

Comment: you are asking 3 questions. you have pasted a lot of code and we have no idea which code is relevant to which part. we also don't know what you have tried already.

Comment: I agree that this should be broken into at least 3 distinct, smaller questions with smaller code examples.